# Print a list item and its X subsequents

Tags: python, list, loops

Input list:

```
a = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Horse']
```

My code:

```
For i in range(len(a)):
    word = a[i]
    if word == 'Cat'
       b = open('file.txt','w')
       b.write(a[i])
```

For now the code iterates and writes Cat into a new file, but I would like to have my program writing Cat and also the subsequent strings, which in these case would be Bird and Horse.

Is there something I could do? i.e: `b.write(a[i:])` or `b.write(a[i:2])`

**Edit:** 
Resolved by using the following:

`b.write('\n'.join(a[i:i+X]))` where X are the subsequent items.

I am still open for better answers. Thanks.

Comment: You can open the file first, and iterate over your list `a` *after* that ;)

Comment: Why do you need to iterate though? Can't you just write the list directly into the file?

Comment: What if the the word (e.g. `'Cat'`) is in the list more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
b.write('\n'.join(a[i:]))
```

if you want a newline to split between the character, if you desire a space, just use `' '.join(a[i:])` e.g.

Comment: you can do `'\n'.join(a[i:i+3])` and throw the IndexError in case (or catch it before)

Answer (score 0):

you can skip the for loop and just do:

```
with open('f', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(a[a.index('Cat'):]))
```